# Poetry add <package> returns AttributeError

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, python, package-management

I am trying to create a Python package using poetry. I haven't been able to replicate the steps described in
[documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/). When I try to add a dependancy, e.g.

```
poetry add pendulum
```

I get

```
jan@jan-XPS-13-9380:~/Documents/Simosol/tmp/poetry-test$ poetry add pendulum
Using version ^2.1.2 for pendulum

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)

  AttributeError

  __enter__

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/utils/helpers.py:98 in download_file
       94│     url, dest, session=None, chunk_size=1024
       95│ ):  # type: (str, str, Optional[requests.Session], int) -> None
       96│     get = requests.get if not session else session.get
       97│ 
    →  98│     with get(url, stream=True) as response:
       99│         response.raise_for_status()
      100│ 
      101│         with open(dest, "wb") as f:
      102│             for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
```

This happens with every package I've tried (pandas, geopandas, numpy, shapely). I don't understand much what is the problem and I haven't found any similar questions on GitHub or here.

**Question:** What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

I use Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9. I have [asked this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625534/poetry-add-package-returns-attributeerror) and was advised it belongs here.